# Nested pointerInput modifiers in compose don't work as expected

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, modifier

I have a grey Box with a purple Box inside it, the purple Box is draggable within the parent grey Box:

[image]

The entire scene can be translated and scaled when touch inputs are outside the purple Box.
But when I scale up the scene and try to drag the purple box, sometimes it moves and sometimes not.
This, for example, is scaled up 2x:

[image]

I don't want this behavior, how to move always the purple box when I touch it?
It looks like the touch slop for moving the purple box is also scaled up.

Here is my code:

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.gestures.detectDragGestures
import androidx.compose.foundation.gestures.detectTapGestures
import androidx.compose.foundation.gestures.detectTransformGestures
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.offset
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.size
import androidx.compose.material.Surface
import androidx.compose.runtime.*
import androidx.compose.runtime.saveable.rememberSaveable
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.geometry.Offset
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.TransformOrigin
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.graphicsLayer
import androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.pointerInput
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.IntOffset
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import com.example.tests3.ui.theme.Tests3Theme
import kotlin.math.roundToInt

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            Tests3Theme {
                Surface(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                    App()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun App() {
    val containerWidth = 302f
    val containerHeight = 358f
    val pieceWidth = 50f
    val pieceHeight = 123f
    var offset by remember { mutableStateOf(Offset.Zero) }
    var zoom by remember { mutableStateOf(1f) }
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .pointerInput(Unit) {
                detectTransformGestures(
                    onGesture = { centroid, pan, gestureZoom, _ ->
                        val oldScale = zoom
                        val newScale = zoom * gestureZoom
                        offset = (offset + centroid / oldScale) - (centroid / newScale + pan / oldScale)
                        zoom = newScale
                    }
                )
            }
            .graphicsLayer {
                translationX = -offset.x * zoom
                translationY = -offset.y * zoom
                scaleX = zoom
                scaleY = zoom
                transformOrigin = TransformOrigin(0f, 0f)
            },
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        Box(modifier = Modifier.size(containerWidth.dp, containerHeight.dp).background(Color(0xFF979797))) {
            var offsetX by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
            var offsetY by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
            Box(
                Modifier
                    .offset { IntOffset(offsetX.roundToInt(), offsetY.roundToInt()) }
                    .background(Color(0xFFFF00FF))
                    .size(pieceWidth.dp, pieceHeight.dp)
                    .pointerInput(Unit) {
                        detectDragGestures { change, dragAmount ->
                            change.consume()
                            offsetX = (offsetX + dragAmount.x).coerceIn(0f..(containerWidth - pieceWidth).dp.toPx())
                            offsetY = (offsetY + dragAmount.y).coerceIn(0f..(containerHeight - pieceHeight).dp.toPx())
                        }
                    }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: looks like `detectDragGestures` has more strict requirements to begin gesture, so in some cases `detectTransformGestures` starts earlier and cancels `detectDragGestures`, despite the fact that it's lower in the modifiers tree. It may be a bug, I suggest you [reporting](https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/new?component=612128) it to see what maintainers think - but there you better provide sample with initial values that will let reproduce it quick and reliable I had to play it for some time to get it.

Comment: Using `detectTransformGestures` instead of `detectDragGestures` seems to be working well, but I guess it may not be perfect for you, since it's gonna prevent topmost gesture from scaling in some cases.